# Method no found with ngx-soap and Angular6

Tags: angular, xml, soap

I'm using NgxSoap + Angular6. I have this problem.

1 Problem (Fig1)
[Method consultarProgramaVersion not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG7lw.png)

2 My client NgxSoap instance is ok.

```js
    constructor(
      private productService: ProductService, 
      private clientService: ClientService, 
      private soap: NgxSoapService
    ) {
      console.log('------------ SOAP INI --------------------');
      this.soap.createClient(
        'assets/sincroService.wsdl'
      ).then(
        client => {
          console.log('Clientsoap???', client);
          this.clientSoap = client;
        }
      ).catch(
        err => console.log('Error client', err)
      );
      console.log('------------ SOAP END --------------------');
    }
```

3 My call from angular => Problem (Fig1)

```js
      message: string;
      xmlResponse: string;
      test() 
      {
        const body = '';
        this.clientSoap.call(
          'consultarProgramaVersion', body
        ).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.xmlResponse = res.responseBody;
            this.message = res.result.AddResult;
          }, 
          err => console.log(err)
        );
      }
```

4 My wsdl
[wsdl](https://mega.nz/file/sDRkmChT#AyA0P8R8nm8LwCeahVkGWRDHkbXFYiPABZzQNgUKM6Q)

5 My wsdl in SOAP-UI works fine this is
[work fine here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWW7d.png)

Finally
I think it has to do with nameSpaces. I have tried but nothing yet. 
Any suggestion... *_*

Comment: would you see the file name and line where this error is throwing. It would be in the console's riight hand corner of that line